# Change year, month and day of NSDate object

Tags: iphone, ios

in my iPhone application I have a start date of event, for exemple: 2013-05-17 15:00:12 +0000. My question is, how can I change 2013-05-17 with today date, but leave time the same?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to gather the date components and amend the required properties.

```
//gather current calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

//gather date components from date
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

//set date components
[dateComponents setDay:17];
[dateComponents setMonth:5];
[dateComponents setYear:2013];

//save date relative from date
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Either that, or you could add the number of seconds in 1 day to increment the value:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:((60 * 60) * 24) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Adding the number of seconds in 1 day assumes that all days have the same amount of seconds. But this will break for a leap second: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit are  Deprecated.
Use: (NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) instead.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3 & IOS 10.2**

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    var dateComponents: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())

    dateComponents?.day = 17
    dateComponents?.month = 5
    dateComponents?.year = 2013

    let date: Date? = calendar.date(from: dateComponents!)
    print(date!)
```

> **Swift 3 & IOS 10.2**

Answer (score 11):

Read more on my blog https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/54

Today I'm trying to change the year of a Date object to 2000 in Swift.

```
let date = Date()
```

Firstly, I tried with `date(bySetting:)` but it does not work with past year. It simply returns nil

```
Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .year, value: 2000, of: date)
```

Secondly, I tried with `dateComponents`. The `component.year` has changed, but it calendar still returns the original date, very strange !!. No matter what timezone and calendar I use, it still has this problem

```
var component = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: base)
component.year = year
Calendar.current.date(from: component)
```

Finally, I tried to be more explicit, and it works

```
var component = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: base)
component.year = year
Calendar.current.date(from: component)
```

Comment: @WilliamT. Hi, I updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: what is base? inside calendar.components

Answer (score 2):

Or in swift:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: NSDate.init())
    components.day = 17
    components.month = 5
    components.year = 2013

    let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find numberOfSeconds of today at 0 am and other date numberOfSeconds at 0 am. Find difference between them. Then to numberOfSeconds of 2013-05-17 15:00:12 +0000 add this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just change the start date with current date and time you desire using the API [dateWithString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . If not then you can probably look at dateByAddingTimeInterval API of NSDate as well by taking diff of timeinterval between two NSDate

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**
 Get-Date which having Year, Month & Day -5 from Current Date

```
    //CurrentDate
    let currentDate = Date()

    let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var components = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate)

    // Change int value which you want to minus from current Date.
    components.day = components.day!-5
    components.month = components.month!-5
    components.year = components.year!-5

    let date = gregorianCalendar.date(from: components)!
    print("Current Date = \(currentDate)")
    print("Old Date = \(date)")
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
    //CurrentDate
    let currentDate = NSDate()

    let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var components = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: currentDate)

    // Change int value which you want to minus from current Date.
    components.day = components.day!-5
    components.month = components.month!-5
    components.year = components.year!-5

    let date = gregorianCalendar.date(from: components)!
    print("Current Date = \(currentDate)")
    print("Old Date = \(date)")
```